# Git add . is not adding the current folder to repo

Tags: git, appharbor, nopcommerce

I want to add a NopCommerce solution to a repository using git.
I entered in the folder where the .sln file is stored and used the `git add . command`.
After that I ran the git commit --dry-run and the output was a little odd, this is the output:

> new file:   Nop.Web
>   new file:   Nop.Web.Framework/.gitignore

The `nop.web` folder was somehow detected, but the content wasn't. Its sibling was detected and all its files were uploaded successfully.

If I go to the `nop.web` folder and use a `git add .` or anything, and after use the `git commit --dry-run` I get a "clean repo" message.

If I perform the push, when I try to build this project in appharbor, the files in the nop.web folder are missing.

Why is this folder missing? How can I add it manually?

Edit: .gitignore from AppHarbor FAQ:

```
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
*.suo
*.user
```

There is a .gitignore in folder that contains a .csproj file. They are all the same

Edit2:

```
D:\nopcommerce\Presentation\Nop.Web>git ls-files --exclude-standard -o

D:\nopcommerce\Presentation\Nop.Web>git diff-index --name-status HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tr
ee.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

That was something interesting I found:

```
D:\nopcommerce\Presentation\Nop.Web>git add ./Administration
fatal: Path 'Presentation/Nop.Web/Administration' is in submodule 'Presentation/
Nop.Web'
```

I will try to look for infos about submodules and how to deal with them

Comment: Could you post the contents of the .gitignore?

Comment: @brian-d added the gitignore content to the question

Comment: could you post the output of `git ls-files --exclude-standard -o` and `git diff-index --name-status HEAD`

Comment: @forivall done. The second command presented some problem that I am trying to fix and run again

Comment: Ooh, you added a submodule. That explains things. Most workflows with submodules are read/fetch-only, but you're trying to add files to one. Googling around will get you some good resources. I was thinking it was some sort of odd windows symlink or junction or something. Also, the "unknown revision" error message is because this is your initial commit, so there is no HEAD yet.

Comment: If I did, I did it unintentionally. I have no ideas how to add submodules :(. If I knew there was a submodule I would give this info, sorry for this gap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the there is a `.gitignore` file added to your repository under that framework. Make sure that it isn't telling git to ignore everything in the folder that you are trying to add.

Comment: added the gitignore file content to the question

Comment: Is there a .git folder in there somewhere? Are you trying to add the source directly when you should instead be adding it as a git submodule?

Comment: this is my directory tree: nopcommerce (where the .sln is found)\Presentation\Nop.Web.
The .git folder is only on the nopcommerce folder

Comment: I deleted the .git folder and used a git init command again. Marking as answer because was during the conversation here and the .git folder question that I started digging and decided to take this approach.