# Cannot add a library folder to git

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have the following folder structure:

```
- Root Project Folder
    |_ App
    |_ Libraries
         |_ AndroidSlidingUpPanel
         |_ Volley
```

I've added the entire project to Git, however, the "Volley" folder (it's a clone of another repository, but I've deleted the .Git folder) cannot be added using "git add ."

Why?

UPDATE

Volley folder content:

```
13/03/2014  16:06               842 .project
13/03/2014  16:06             1.071 Android.mk
13/03/2014  16:06               290 AndroidManifest.xml
08/03/2014  19:27               828 build.gradle
13/03/2014  16:06             4.010 build.xml
13/03/2014  16:06               349 custom_rules.xml
13/03/2014  16:06               801 proguard-project.txt
13/03/2014  16:06             1.288 proguard.cfg
13/03/2014  16:06               512 project.properties
13/03/2014  16:06              src
13/03/2014  16:06              tests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was from another repository, I would recommend the git pattern of [using submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to handle this.

However, if you're looking to just add the project without using submodules, I would look at these two questions. Make sure to remove all .git files from the directory, as that will prevent it from adding appropriately.

- https://superuser.com/questions/583673/cant-add-folder-in-git
- [Git add . is not adding the current folder to repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859952/git-add-is-not-adding-the-current-folder-to-repo)

Comment: The folder is not empty.

Comment: Do you get any messages from git when you perform the add? Also, if you have a gitignore file, it's possible that what you have setup in the gitignore file is ignoring all files in the volley folder, preventing it from being added.

Comment: Here is the content of the gitignore file in the Volley folder: bin
gen
.gradle
build
.settings

Comment: What is in the the Volley folder? If all content matches the gitignore file, that would prevent the folder from being added.

Comment: If it's a submodule, I have to use another git init for it? Will it be a separate repository?

Comment: I don't want to keep it connected to the original repository. Can I unlink it and commit to my own repository normally?